# Recoger JSON desde una API con Angular 2

Tags: json, angularjs-2.0, api

Trato de recoger en un servicio el JSON proporcionado por una API que he creado, pero por lo que sea no lo recibe.

```
getLibro(id: string){
    return this._http.get(this.url + 'libros/' + id)
               .map(res => {
                   console.log(res.json()); //No muestra nada
                   return res.json();
               })
```

Sin embargo el método *getLibros()* no tiene problemas al recoger la información.
A continuación, todo el servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class LibrosService {

url: string = "http://localhost/API/public/index.php/api/";

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getLibros(){
    return this._http.get(this.url + 'libros')
                .map(res => res.json());        //recoge el json perfectamene
}

getLibro(id: string){
    return this._http.get(this.url + 'libros/' + id)
               .map(res => {
                   console.log(res.json());     //No muestra nada
                   return res.json();
               })
}
```

Agradezco la ayuda de ante mano.

Comment: ¿Algún error en la consola? ¿las cabeceras te aparecen correctas en el navegador?

Comment: Sin errores aparentes.

Comment: Pestaña network que resulta de tu petición?

Comment: Qué proceso buscas en concreto.

Comment: necesitamos ver resultados de consola, o la peticion de network en chrome, que nos de status, endpoints, datos... si no, no se te puede ayudar, es dificil sin mas datos saber q pasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afortunadamente, me han ayudado a encontrar la solución porque lo más frustrante de todo era que no aparecían errores por consola. Y el problema no estaba en el servicio si no en el componente.

He aquí mi solución:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { LibrosService } from "app/services/libros.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-libro',
  templateUrl: './libro.component.html'
})
export class LibroComponent implements OnInit {

  public libro: any =[];
  private sub: Subscription;
  public errorMessage: string;

  constructor( private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
               private _librosService: LibrosService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._activatedRoute.params
                   .subscribe(params => {
                        let id = +params['id'];
                        this.getLib(id);
                    });
  }

  getLib(id){
      this._librosService.getLibro(id)
          .subscribe(libro => {
              this.libro = libro,
              error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
          });
  }
}
```

Gracias a todos los que os habéis interesado.

Comment: felicitaciones hermano :D te sugiero que marques esta respuesta como aceptada (click en el check verde) de tal manera que ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas con respuestas aceptadas). Saludos :D